# HTMLUnit: lot of errors

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying out HTMLUnit to automate downloading data off a web app. However, I am getting a whole mess of warnings on getPage(), actually I have no idea about what is happening, can anyone help me???

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptResult;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class TwitterBot {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         try{

         WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);

         HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://twitter.com");
         HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("loginform");
         form.getInputByName("Phone, email or username").setValueAttribute(#####);
         form.getInputByName("Password").setValueAttribute(#####);
         page1 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Log In").click();

         System.out.println(page1.getTitleText());
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
     }

}
```

and this is what I get

```
 Jun 16, 2015 8:28:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet isValidSelector WARNING: Unhandled CSS condition type '7'. Accepting it silently. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector:
    *:x).] sourceName=[https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.5d3ccdc0a32f0d80ef94f5c67f8b3c4c679d57bb.js] line=[108] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
 Jun 16, 2015 8:28:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_core.bundle.css' [1:49012] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_core.bundle.css' [1:53686] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_logged_out.bundle.css' [1:23822] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
 Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:31558] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:31582] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:76744] Invalid color "#ccd6dd\9". 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:161131] Error in class selector. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting: <IDENT>.) 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:161131] Ignoring the whole rule. 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:247550] Error in expression. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.) 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css' [9:247569] Error in expression. (Invalid token "}". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.) 
Jun 16, 2015 8:28:26 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING: CSS error: 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1434379534/css/t1/twitter_more_2.bundle.css' [1:92384] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
 Jun 16, 2015 8:28:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
```

Comment: Is the data being download though?

Comment: You can ignore those warnings, since some JavaScript frameworks test with invalid CSS selectors sometimes. HtmlUnit logs those errors. Please specify if you have an issue getting what you need from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before declaring the **webClient**, it should remove the unnecessary logs by HtmlUnit:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```